# Slides Go Wrong Way on Arrow Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slider

I have a 3 image slider. Clicking on both the top and bottom arrow results in the slides going down, progressing "slide one, slide two, slide three" instead of "slide one, slide three, slide two" on up arrow click.

[You can see what I have so far on my codepen.](https://codepen.io/ethereality/pen/xpbxxz)
[I'm editing code from this PageRevealEffects tutorial.](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PageRevealEffects/)

I'm pretty sure I've narrowed down the issue in the javascript file, but the shorthand nature of the function is tripping me up.

I think these are the troublesome lines in question:

```js
onStart: function(direction) {
    // next page gets class page--animate-[direction]
    var nextPage = pages[currentPage === 0 ? 0 : currentPage];
    classie.add(nextPage, 'page--animate-' + direction);
  },
  onEnd: function(direction) {
    // remove class page--animate-[direction] from next page
    var nextPage = pages[currentPage === 0 ? pages.length - 1 : 0];
    nextPage.className = 'page';
  }
```

And this:

```js
function reveal(direction) {
  var callbackTime = 750,
    callbackFn = function() {
      classie.remove(pages[currentPage], "page--current");
      currentPage = currentPage < pages.length - 1 ? currentPage + 1 : 0;
      classie.add(pages[currentPage], "page--current");
    };
  revealer.reveal(direction, callbackTime, callbackFn);
}
})();
```

Here is the full .js file.

```js
(function() {
  console.log("I loaded!");
  var pages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".pages > .page")),
    currentPage = 0,
    revealerOpts = {
      // the layers are the elements that move from the sides
      nmbLayers: 1,
      // bg color of each layer
      bgcolor: ["gray"],
      // effect classname
      effect: "anim--effect-1",
      onStart: function(direction) {
        // next page gets class page--animate-[direction]
        var nextPage = pages[currentPage === 0 ? 0 : currentPage];
        classie.add(nextPage, "page--animate-" + direction);
      },
      onEnd: function(direction) {
        // remove class page--animate-[direction] from next page
        var nextPage = pages[currentPage === 0 ? pages.length - 1 : 0];
        nextPage.className = "page";
      }
    };
  revealer = new Revealer(revealerOpts);

  // clicking the page nav buttons
  document
    .querySelector("button.pagenav__button--top")
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
      reveal("top");
    });
  document
    .querySelector("button.pagenav__button--bottom")
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
      reveal("bottom");
    });

  // triggers the effect by calling instance.reveal(direction, callbackTime, callbackFn)
  function reveal(direction) {
    var callbackTime = 750,
      callbackFn = function() {
        classie.remove(pages[currentPage], "page--current");
        currentPage = currentPage < pages.length - 1 ? currentPage + 1 : 0;
        classie.add(pages[currentPage], "page--current");
      };
    revealer.reveal(direction, callbackTime, callbackFn);
  }
})();
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried simply switching the directions passed to `reveal()` in your click events?

Comment: Yes, I have. For whatever reason, it goes down regardless of what direction is stated in the click events.

Comment: Anyone else have any thoughts?

Comment: I couldn't figure this out, but as a hack, I just disabled the up arrow.